# Multi-Threading with selenium and Python Background processing

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver

I currently trying to auto login into a website and fill a form.
I'm using selenium in python and am trying to multi thread each username in a different driver.

Issue is that drivers does open parallel to each other in the background yet they seem to not process the data unless they are opened in the foreground which does delay the process alot to wait for one to finish then process the next.

for confidentiality reasons I cannot share the website URL yet here is the code and functions used.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,ElementClickInterceptedException,TimeoutException
from threading import Thread
import time
import pandas as pd
```

Chrome options:-

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--enable-javascript')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/15.0 Safari/605.1.15'
chrome_options.add_argument('User-Agent={0}'.format(user_agent))
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', True)
```

Functions used:-

```
def login_hbd(driver,username,password):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME,"username")))
    
    username_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"username")
    username_field.send_keys(username)

    password_field = driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password")
    password_field.send_keys(password)
    
    submit_btn = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submitBtn")))

    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", submit_btn)
    
def get_ss_hbd(driver,username_list,password_list):
    while True:
        try:
            login_hbd(driver,str(username_list),password_list)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 1).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH,"/html/body/div[1]/div/div/header/div/div[3]/nav/ul/li[7]/a")))
            driver.get("*****")
            driver.save_screenshot(f"{username_list}.png")         
            driver.close()
            break

        except (NoSuchElementException,ElementClickInterceptedException,TimeoutException):
            continue
```

Threading code:-

```
# get the start time
st = time.time()
number_of_threads = len(df)
threads = []

for _ in range(number_of_threads):
    username_list = df.loc[_][0]
    password_list = df.loc[_][1]
    driver = uc.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options,service_args=['--quiet'])
    driver.get("****")
    t = Thread(target=get_ss_hbd, args=(driver,username_list,password_list)) 
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for t in threads:
    t.join()
et = time.time()

# get the execution time
elapsed_time = et - st
print('Execution time:', elapsed_time, 'seconds')
```

Comment: Selenium isn't thread-safe. You can try python playwright for something async.

Comment: @pguardiario Not compatible with windows and not thread safe as well as per their documentation https://playwright.dev/python/docs/library#incompatible-with-selectoreventloop-of-asyncio-on-windows

Comment: It's async which is a different kind of concurrency than threads, and it sounds like there's a workaround for Windows.

Comment: What about the `multiprocessing` module? You may want to use it instead of the `threading` module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referencing to this issue https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver/issues/1051

and running the following code to fix the issues with `undetected_chromedriver`

code:

```
python -m pip uninstall undetected-chromedriver
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/undetected-chromedriver@fix-multiple-instance
python -m pip install --upgrade selenium
```